# Working out relative abundances with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have my data:

```
library(dplyr)
Sample.no <- c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2)
Group <-c('a','b','c','a','b','a','b','c','d','a','c')
Abundance <- c(Sample.no*c(3,1,4,7,2))
df<-data.frame(Sample.no,Group,Abundance)
```

giving

```
Sample.no Group Abundance
1   1        a       3
2   1        b       1
3   1        c       4
4   2        a       14
5   2        b       4
6   1        a       3
7   1        b       1
8   1        c       4
9   1        d       7
10  2        a       4
11  2        c       6
```

I want to create a summary simmilar to this:

```
df<-group_by(df,Sample.no)
df<-summarise(df,number=n(),total=sum(Abundance))

Sample.no   number  total
  1   1          7       23

  2   2          4       28
```

however i'd also like a column with the total Abundance of 'a's in each sample in order to work out relative abundance. I've tried custom functions with no success, is there an easy way to do it in dplyr?

Comment: Just add `sum(Group == "a")` to `summarise`? As in `df %>% group_by(Sample.no) %>% summarise(number = n(), total = sum(Number), a = sum(Group == "a"))` ?

Comment: this gives me the number of times 'a' occurs in either sample (so 2 in each) but not the actual amount (as in the sum of the values from the Number column)

Comment: @Tom - a simple adjustment then - `df %>% group_by(Sample.no) %>% summarise(number=n(), total=sum(Number), atotal=sum(Number[Group=="a"]))`

Comment: thank you this works perfectly!

Comment: And as for the English- "*the number of 'a's*" means the number of times `a` occurs, so please rephrase your request in a way that we can understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6
setDT(df)[, c(list(num = .N, tot = sum(Abundance)), 
                   tapply(Abundance, Group, sum)), 
            by = Sample.no]
#    Sample.no num tot  a b c  d
# 1:         1   7  23  6 2 8  7
# 2:         2   4  28 18 4 6 NA
```

I use `tapply()` instead of joins using `.SD` since we need a named list here, and `tapply()`'s output format makes is very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` and `xtabs`:

```
total <- aggregate(Abundance ~ Sample.no, data=df, 
                   FUN = function(x) c(num = length(x), total = sum(x)))
group <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Abundance ~ Sample.no + Group, df))
cbind(total, group)
```

Output:

```
  Sample.no Abundance.num Abundance.total  a b c d
1         1             7              23  6 2 8 7
2         2             4              28 18 4 6 0
```